# How to get all img and its attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

`

```
<ul class="flickr-badge-content">
    <li class="first">
        <img data-photo-attribution="andysouthwales" data-photo-page="http://www.flickr.com/photos/andysouthwales/1212121/" data-photo-title="abcd" data-photo-id="1212121" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2855/1212121_ce6bfd5c38_s.jpg"></img>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img data-photo-attribution="andysouthwales" data-photo-page="http://www.flickr.com/photos/andysouthwales/1263324993173/" data-photo-title="tennn" data-photo-id="1263324993173" src="http://farm8.static.flickr.com/7457/1263324993173_0e3e9745f8_s.jpg"></img>
    </li>
    <li>..............</ul>.......
```

I want to get all image and their attributes. Please Help...

Comment: and what have you tried???

Comment: start with `$(".flickr-badge-content img")`

Comment: `<img>` is a self-closing element: `<img src... />`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cycle through all of the images attributes by using

```
$('img').each(function(currentImage){
    console.log(currentImage.data('photo-attribution')); //log some attribute
});
```

I'm sure that you will figure the rest out.

Answer (score 2):

I have provided you an example which selects all the `image` tag and gets the `source` attribute of each of them. You can use this to get `whichever attribute` you want.

Using `JavaScript`

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); 
var srcList = [];//This is just for the src attribute
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    srcList.push(images[i].src);
 }
```

Instead of `document.getElementsByTagName('img')` you could also use the `document.images` collection.

```
function allSrc() {
  var src = [];
  var imgs = document.images;
  for (var i=0, iLen=imgs.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    src[i] = imgs[i].src;
  }
  return src;
}
```

Using `Jquery`:

```
var srcList = $('img').map(function() {
   return this.src;
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var images = $("img");
        for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) { 
        alert($(images[i]).attr("data-photo-attribution"));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
$('.flickr-badge-content li img').each(function(){
var data = $(this).data();
for(var i in data){
  $('<li>', {
      text: i + ': ' + data[i]
  }).appendTo('.flickr-badge-content');
}});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WVfSg/236/)**